# how to get Circular image View on api < 20 (Android)

Tags: android, android-imageview, ondraw

this is how am getting circularImageView on api 23

```
    public class CustomImageViewCircularShape extends ImageView {

    public static float radius = 100.0f;

    public CustomImageViewCircularShape(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public CustomImageViewCircularShape(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public CustomImageViewCircularShape(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        Path clipPath = new Path();
        RectF rect = new RectF(0, 0, this.getWidth(), this.getHeight());
        clipPath.addRoundRect(rect, radius, radius, Path.Direction.CW);
        canvas.clipPath(clipPath);
        super.onDraw(canvas);
    }
}
```

but its not working on api 16  also  android Studio is not giving any warning related  to Backward Support ?  any idea why  its not working or how i can make it work on the older Apis ?

Comment: Maybe this library can help you https://github.com/hdodenhof/CircleImageView

Comment: @harry exactly what i was looking for

Comment: i forgot to add thanks :D @harry

Comment: No problem mate. Glad it worked out for you.

Answer (score 1):

One alternative way would be using Fresco library from Facebook. Among all its features, you can use circular images.

Here you have more information.

http://frescolib.org/docs/rounded-corners-and-circles.html

For an approach like yours, try this one:
https://gist.github.com/melanke/7158342

Comment: thanks for responding man :) , appreciate your effort  .   harry's library did the job